# Mysql Count Distinct results

Tags: mysql, database, count, distinct

I need a query to Count distinct results...

My Table

```
ID | stats | name
-----------------
1  | 1     | John
2  | 1     | John
3  | 2     | John
4  | 2     | John
5  | 3     | John
```

i need query like this....

```
SELECT if( stats = 2, ADD + 1, 0) as ok, if(stats = 3, ADD + 1, 0) as no_ok
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? What output are you expecting?

Comment: in my html, i need twoo results for buttons

Comment: button ok = 15
button no_ok = 4

Comment: What is `ADD`?  Where exactly do you get `15` and `4` as your final results?  Can you show calculation steps and expected results of your query?

Comment: ADD is a "example" I need count stats, like this <br />
if(stats == 2)
$ok++;
elseif(stats == 3)
$no_ok++;

Comment: So from your example, I see 2 rows with `stats == 2`, and 2 rows with `stats == 3`.  How do you get from 2 and 2, to 15 and 4?  Also, why are you then comparing `stats = 1` and `stats = 2` in your sample query, and saying your logic is `stats == 2` and `stats == 3`?  You need to lay out your algorithm in clear, precise steps and be consistent.  Also, provide a complete example that represents the answer for the *data you posted*, not your expected results for some dataset we can't see.

Comment: i need 1 row and 2 results count(ok), count(no_ok). "ok" (stats = 2) "no_ok" (stats = 3).

Comment: OK, I think I follow you. See the answer I posted and let me know if it helps.  (**Edit**: I said 2 rows with `stats == 3` in my comment above, I meant *1* row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simultaneously count the number of rows with multiple specific criteria in a data set, you can use the pattern `COUNT(CASE WHEN criteria THEN 1 END)`.  Here's an example that counts the number of rows for `stats = 2`, and for `stats = 3`:

```
SELECT
  count(case when stats = 2 then 1 end) as ok,
  count(case when stats = 3 then 1 end) as not_ok
from
  Table1
```

Results:

```
OK | NOT_OK
-----------
2  | 1
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82414/1